# Can you left join in R (all.x = TRUE) and keep non-matching cases in their original positions, rather than appending?

Tags: r

Is it possible to left join/merge in R while preserving the original ordering of the `by` column in the left dataframe? The default behavior is that non-matching cases are appended to the end of the merged data frame, but this obviously changes the ordering.

Is there a simple solution I'm missing, or a clever way around this?

Here is an example with a non-matching case for `id == 3`, in the second row of the left dataframe `df1`:

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(4,3,2,1),
                 color = c('purple','red','blue','green'))
df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,4),
                 weight = c(4.1, 5.3, 1.8))
```

```
df1
#   id   color
# 1  4  purple
# 2  3     red
# 3  2    blue
# 4  1   green

df2
#   id weight
# 1  1    4.1
# 2  2    5.3
# 3  4    1.8
```

If you merge with the default `sort = TRUE`, then the non-matching case appears in its place in the sorted `by` column. In this case, the third row:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'id', all.x = TRUE)
#   id  color weight
# 1  1  green    4.1
# 2  2   blue    5.3
# 3  3    red     NA
# 4  4 purple    1.8
```

If you want to preserve ordering with `sort = FALSE`, then non-matching cases are appended to the bottom of the merged dataframe, as it clearly states in the documentation for `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'id', all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
#   id  color weight
# 1  4 purple    1.8
# 2  2   blue    5.3
# 3  1  green    4.1
# 4  3    red     NA
```

What I'd like is to preserve the original ordering of the left `df1`, including the non-matching cases, rather than preserve the ordering only for matching cases. My goal is to produce this:

```
#   id  color weight
# 1  4 purple    1.8
# 2  3    red     NA
# 3  2   blue    5.3
# 4  1  green    4.1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: use `left_join` i.e. `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)` preserves the original order

Comment: A more general (but also more complicated) solution is to add a column with the order before sorting, and then use it for sorting after. For example, `df1$order1 <- 1:nrow(df1) ; ... merge ... ; dfcomb <- dfcomb[order(dfcomb$order1), ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = data.frame(id = c(4,3,2,1),
                 color = c('purple','red','blue','green'))
df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,4),
                 weight = c(4.1, 5.3, 1.8))

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, 
            by = "id")
```

Result:

```
  id  color weight
1  4 purple    1.8
2  3    red     NA
3  2   blue    5.3
4  1  green    4.1
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you much